# Cloning VM without network adapter

Tags: c#, vmware, vsphere

I'm using .NET `VMware` assembly called `VMware.Vim.dll` to manage my vms. The issue I am facing is: when I'm cloning my existing vm, which has no network adapter, the resulting vm has a new network adapter.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
var machineName = "testVmName";
var vmNameFilter = new NameValueCollection();
filter.Add("Name", machineName);

var vm = (VirtualMachine)this._vimClient.FindEntityView(typeof(VirtualMachine), null, vmNameFilter, null); 

var dcNameFilter = new NameValueCollection();
dcNameFilter.Add("Name", _dataCenterName);

var dataCenter = (Datacenter)this._vimClient.FindEntityView(typeof(Datacenter), null, dcNameFilter, null);

var vmCloneSpec = new VirtualMachineCloneSpec
{
    Location = new VirtualMachineRelocateSpec
    {
    },
    PowerOn = false,
    Template = false
};

vm.CloneVM(dataCenter.VmFolder, newVmName, vmCloneSpec)
```

How can I force the API to not create new network adapter?

Comment: It looks to me like you need to look into the documentation.. for example a quick google turned up you probably want to look at the `config` property of the `vmCloneSpec` see: https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk400pubs/ReferenceGuide/vim.vm.ConfigSpec.html

Comment: does the same occur, when you do this task manually?

Comment: From the API you can also take VM snapshots that contain the config settings so you might want to look into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm no expert on this topic but it looks to me like this is what you want to do.

From looking at the documentation for [VirtualMachineCloneSpec](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk400pubs/ReferenceGuide/vim.vm.CloneSpec.html) it seems there is a property called `config`. This property then has one called `netowrkShaper` which in turn has one called `enabled`. My guess is to try doing something like the following:

```
vmCloneSpec.config.netowrkShaper.enabled = false;
```

or more than likely seeing as they are custom objects:

```
vmCloneSpec.config = new VirtualMachineConfigSpec()
{
    networkShaper = new VirtualMachineNetworkShaperInfo()
    {
        enabled = false;
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell from the docs this could be what you're looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem :( The result is still the same.

Comment: @Sini4ka Okay, have you looked into taking snapshots?

Comment: no, I haven't. What do you mean? Take snapshot and then clone from it?

Comment: @Sini4ka I don't have time to look into it but heres the relevant page in the docs https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk400pubs/ReferenceGuide/vim.VirtualMachine.html#createSnapshot

Comment: i've tried to take snapshot and clone from this snapshot. And it works for me! Thanks for your time and problem solution suggestion.

Comment: @Sini4ka No worries, feel free to add an answer to your question so that others can see a solution